# Using parameters of Stored Procedure with Join's "ON" area

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, join, case-when

I have parameters like these

```
declare @Phl1_descr varchar(50)
SET @Phl1_descr = 'Greece'

declare @Phl2_descr varchar(50)
SET @Phl2_descr = 'Coffee & Beverages'
```

I want to join two tables with the above parameters **(if they are not null)**, so I tried to do something like below in the "`ON`" keyword of my `JOIN`

```
ON 
      (CASE WHEN LEN(@Phl1_descr) > 0 THEN A.Phl1_descr ELSE B.Phl1_descr END) = B.Phl1_descr AND
      (CASE WHEN LEN(@Phl2_descr) > 0 THEN A.Phl2_descr ELSE B.Phl2_descr END) = B.Phl2_descr
```

However if I send one of the parameters like as `''`, it doesn't work. Any simpler idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting but

```
B.Phl1_descr = B.Phl1_descr
```

not working but

```
ISNULL(B.Phl1_descr,'-1') = ISNULL(B.Phl1_descr,'-1')
```

works,

So just a simple change in the below code work it out

```
  (CASE WHEN LEN(@Phl1_descr) > 1 THEN A.Phl1_descr ELSE ISNULL(B.Phl1_descr,'-1') END) = ISNULL(B.Phl1_descr,'-1') AND
  (CASE WHEN LEN(@Phl2_descr) > 1 THEN A.Phl2_descr ELSE ISNULL(B.Phl2_descr,'-1') END) = ISNULL(B.Phl2_descr,'-1') AND
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it posible to use simpler solution? Like:

```
IF @Phl1_descr IS NOT NULL AND @Phl2_descr IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM Table1 as A
   LEFT JOIN Table2 as B on A.Phl1_descr=B.Phl1_descr and A.Phl2_descr=B.Phl2_descr
END
ELSE IF @Phl1_descr IS NOT NULL AND @Phl2_descr IS NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM Table1 as A
   LEFT JOIN Table2 as B on A.Phl1_descr=B.Phl1_descr
END
ELSE IF @Phl1_descr IS NULL AND @Phl2_descr IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM Table1 as A
   LEFT JOIN Table2 as B on A.Phl2_descr=B.Phl2_descr
END
```

So you will get a simpler execution plans and simpler logic.

You can also use `... CASE WHEN @Phl1_descr IS NULL THEN ...` to check NULL values

Comment: didn't try because I have find a solution, but anyway my stored procedures are too long to write as simple as in your solution. anyway +1 as my appreciation. Thanks